# Tomcat server startup script fails in Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat

Getting below exception while executing startup.sh for Tomcat. Please help me to resolve

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

I'm using RedHat Linux, tomcat version is 6.0.26

When I use java simply I face the same exception.

I set the JAVA_HOME and path varaible in /etc/profile as

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_30  
export JAVA_HOME  

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH  
export PATH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this error means one of two things.

1. The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found. This could be as simple as somebody renaming a `.jar` file. Can you ensure nothing has vital has changed in the path?
2. Some other script is overriding Classpath environment variable. Can you run you try running java explicity with the `-classpath` option with the classpath you believe will work?

Comment: Actually I did a mistake. I downloaded a .bin file for linux from oracle site and extracted in Windows then deployed in Linux. Instead of this, I extracted the .bin file in Linux itself to resolve this. Basically JVM was corrupted when that error was come